# Laravel - Multiple models in one controller

Tags: model-view-controller, laravel-5, controllers

I have the following database structure:

`Enquiries`

> id
>
> total_widgets
>
> total_amount
>
> customer_id

`Customers`

> id,
>
> first_name,
>
> last_name

Using the form when you are creating an Enquiry you can enter the Customers details into the section and this will store using `firstOrCreate` and then get the `id` in order to link to `Enquiry` to the `Customer`

Now, the issue is that this is all done inside the `store` method within the `Customers` controller, like the following:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     $rules = array(
         "first_name" => "required", 
         "last_name" => "required", 
         "total_widgets" => "required"
     );

     // Handle validation 

     // Create customer
     $customer = \App\Customers::firstOrCreate(['first_name' => $request-
                 >get('first_name')]); 

     $enquiry = new \App\Enquiries(); 
     $enquiry->customer_id = $customer->id; 
     $enquiry->save(); 

}
```

The issue with doing it like this is that it's not separated out and that if the process of creating a customer changes, then I would need to change this a lot of times. (Everytime I have a section which requires a customer)..

Is there a better way to do this? For example, should the customer be created separately and then the id is passed into the `$request`?

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is :

1) In Enquiries form add button called "add new customer".

2) When you click on this button a modal will appear and then fill details click submit.

3) On clicking submit make an ajax call to Customercontroller and insert the data then return the last inserted  id.

4) Now you can see the new user in drop down box(There will be some drop down for selecting the user) of enquirey form just select it and then press submit.

5) It will passed to the enquirey controller and and store it.

Hope this will help you.